# Getting an error when inverting an integer type matrix in torch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, torch

I was attempting to find the inverse of a 3x3 matrix that is composed of random integers using: `torch.randint()`. However, when doing so, I was getting the error: *"inverse_cpu" not implemented for 'Long'*

The code:

```
A = torch.randint(0, 10, (3, 3))
A_inv = A.inverse()
print(A @ A_inv, "\n", A_inv @ A)
```

I believe that `A.inverse()` is expecting the inverse of matrix A to also be of type integer, but it's not. Maybe we can have it such that matrix A is of type float like `torch.Tensor()`, or have A_inv invert it regardless. Though I'm not quite sure how to do either.

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured out 2 ways to do this:

1.) `A = torch.randint(0, 10, (3, 3), dtype=torch.float32)`

2.) `A = torch.Tensor(np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 3)))`

And then inverting either gives no errors, as both are of type float32 now.

Comment: Most DL objects are filled with either float32 or float64. Apparently, some PyTorch ops are not even implemented with longint